# How to do digital signature through selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Below is my code to draw digital signature in a document.But driver is not able to capture the signature. Please find the attached image and let me know how can I achieve this.

```
WebElement text = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("expression"));
Actions actionBuilder = new Actions(webDriver);          
Action drawAction = actionBuilder.moveToElement(text,660,96)
                    .click()
                    .clickAndHold(text)
                    .moveByOffset(120, 120)
                    .moveByOffset(60,70)
                    .moveByOffset(-140,-140)
                    .release(text)
                     .build();
drawAction.perform();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element is not ready for accepting mouse events when you located that element. Try to add some waiting.

Comment: Tried with the below, but it's not working.Just entering a dot in the signature box :                         WebElement text=webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='capsig-drawing-board']/div/canvas"));
 
 try{
 Actions actionBuilder=new Actions(webDriver);
 actionBuilder.build();
 
 actionBuilder.moveToElement(text,660,96)
                     .clickAndHold();
                     webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 actionBuilder.moveByOffset(600, 100)
                     .moveByOffset(696, 140)
                     .release();
 actionBuilder.perform();
 }

Comment: Could you move actionBuilder.build(); to be just before actionBuilder.perform()?